# mysql sub query to get latest comment from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on a query to get summarised list of communications like an inbox that shows conversations

below are my tables

### users

company | contact_person | pic_small

### alerts

comment_id | user_id | poster_id | timestamp

### activity

comment_id | user_id | comment | timestamp

### comments

comment_id | user_id | comment | timestamp

This is what I have so far which works ok although I need help with one aspect.

```
SELECT alerts.comment_id,
       alerts.user_id,
       alerts.poster_id,
       alerts.active,
       MAX(alerts.timestamp) AS maxTime,
       users.contact_person,
       users.company,
       users.pic_small
FROM alerts
LEFT JOIN users ON users.user_id = alerts.poster_id
WHERE alerts.user_id = %s
GROUP BY alerts.comment_id
ORDER BY maxTime DESC
```

Comments are held in the activity and comments tables and I need to somehow join the last (newest) comment from either the activity or comments table (depending which is newer)

How do I add this to my above query, below is what I am trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: For me its not clear how the alerts and activity/comments are related. Is alert the root for `n` activities/comments? Can you draw a database diagram that shows the relations?

Comment: they are related by comment_id.

Comment: Every time there is message activity it records it in the alerts table so the users can be alerted. The first message only gets recorded in the activity table and then all messages from then on go in the messages table. My query works but falls short as I want to grab the very last message (could be activity or comments table) - joined by message id